# Outline Eevee Shader with Transparency

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

[image]

[image]

Hi, I'm using the solidify modifier with backfacing in the material Editor to create a real-time shader in Eevee. It works great for solid materials. But with Transparency materials, since it's applying the outline material to the backface. It shows up in the background of the material, since it's transparent.

I'd like to just keep the outlines around the edges. Do you have any ideas or solutions as to how to accomplish this? Trying to achieve this look: https://www.instagram.com/p/B0CYcugFG3R/?igshid=18twn5kbifu7m

I'm working on a toon tutorial for my YouTube channel at southernshotty 3D, if that affects you wanting to answer. I'll credit anybody who helps me find a solution in the video  I'm going to keep trying some things. If I find a solution I'll post it here. Thank you!